# Explicitly Disallowing Compiler Generated Functions

Tags: c++

Lately I have been working through Meyers' Effective C++ Third Edition. For a project I am currently working on I have had to create a class that I explicitly want to disallow the use of compiler generated functions. I implemented code using Item 6 in said book as a reference, the only major difference in that my class is Templated. The code for it is as follows

```
template <class T>
class Uncopyable
{
protected:
    Uncopyable<T>(){}
    virtual ~Uncopyable<T>(){}
private:
    Uncopyable<T>(const Uncopyable<T>&);
    Uncopyable<T>& operator=(const Uncopyable<T>&);
};
```

My test function.

```
class Test : private Uncopyable<Test>
{
public:
    Test(){}
    ~Test(){}
    inline void test()
    {
        std::cout << "blah" << std::endl;
    }
private:
protected:
};
```

When used like this the code works completely as expected

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test t1, t2;

    // Works as expected, doesnt allow copying of object
    t2 = t1;
    // and this works fine, no copying
    Test t3 = t2;

    // finally, works correctly no copying is allowed
    Test t4(t1);

    return 0;
}
```

When used like this however, the code compiles fine and copying can take place, when it should not be able to?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test* t1 = new Test(), *t2;
    t1->test();
    // Works when it shouldnt work?
    t2 = t1;
    t2->test();

    // same with this
    Test* t3 = t2;
    t3->test();

    // and this
    Test* t4(t1);
    t4->test();

    delete t1;

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried it without the template class and the result is the same, so I don't think that is the issue.

So SO, why is this allowed to happen? Is there an error in my code, or am I just understanding the concept wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're copying the pointer, not the object.  Try this:

```
*t2 = *t1;
```

Comment: Don't try that... `t2` isn't initialised... not that it matters, it should not campile, as expected.

Comment: @Mankarse it's fine; the assignment operator won't be called so there's no UB.

Comment: Right... yes... it won't compile... *facepalm*.

Answer (score 2):

Your changed code is copying the *pointers*, rather than the `Test` objects themselves.

`t1`, `t2`, `t3` and `t4` all end up pointing to the *same* object, and this object is never copied.

Answer (score 2):

There are two important things here:

1. A type, and a pointer to that type are two very different things.
2. Copying a pointer will not copy what it points to.

Take this block, for example:

```
Test* t1 = new Test(), *t2;
t1->test();
// Works when it shouldnt work?
t2 = t1;
```

Your `t1` object is not copied here. There is only one instance of the class in memory, but there are now two references to it. If you call `delete` on `t2`, it will destroy that single copy and your other reference, `t1`, will now be pointing at an invalid memory location.

I'm not certain you can prevent the copying of raw pointers, but even if you could a programmer could trivially cast your `Test*` to `void*`, copy the pointer, and then cast it back to `Test*`. If you want to prevent copying of any sort of references, you will need to use smart pointers and private constructors and that's a whole new question!

Answer (score 0):

**Compiler generated functions** are called in *C++ standart* as **special functions**
Whey are **called so** especially due to 2 factors:
**1.** they are generated by compiler(if not generated by user);
**2.** they take as an argument object of the same class (except ~destructor).

So for **pointers on object** such function **not generated**.
Also in **C++ 11 standart**, instead of declaring functions what you want to hide in `private` area you can use `delete` statement.